# Null pointer using threads and drawing canvas on view, android beginner, logcat included

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, android-canvas

I've been following a tutorial [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-displaying.html).

So far i have a Gameview and a Gameloop (a thread) set up alright but i just modified the run() method in my thread and i get this error in logcat:

- ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296): java.lang.NullPointerException
- ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296):     at biz.hireholly.tutorial.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:76)

Which i'm guessing means line 76 is the problem?

that's: **canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();**

I've commented this in my code snippet below:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting Game Loop");
    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        //try locking canvas, so only we can edit pixels on surface
        try{
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(); //LINE 76
            synchronized (surfaceHolder){ 
                this.gameView.onDraw(canvas);
            }
        } finally{
            //in case of exception, 
            //surface is not left in an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**See the whole GameLoop class code here: http://pastebin.com/kfTy9vzY**

**Andd you can see my GameView class here: http://pastebin.com/BkmnrUPU**

(They're both pretty short)

I've been trying to figure it out for myself a few days now with google and just general fiddling but I've been unable too, i would very much appreciate anyone's thoughts on the matter!

Comment: what is `surfaceHolder` ? Is it initialized?

Comment: @hage oh surfaceHolder allowes me to lock the the canvas so that my program has exclusive access to the pixels, from the documentation: "Abstract interface to someone holding a display surface. Allows you to control the surface size and format, edit the pixels in the surface, and monitor changes to the surface. " I've declared it as a global object but now that you mention it i haven't assigned it a value? i'll add the full class code to my question, thanks for looking!

Comment: I don't know anything about android development, but it seems like you get the `surfaceHolder` from the Framework class `SurfaceView`. You should use a debugger and check what `getHolder()` returns.

Comment: @hage Thanks your right about SUrfaceView, not sure how to check what getHolder returns with the debugger but now ive got something i can lookup it's a step in the right direction at least.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line and check the value of surfaceView, then work your way backwards. The only way you can get a NPE from that line is if surfaceView is null

Comment: @EricRosenberg , Thanks i took your advice and you're correct the surfaceHolder is null when perhaps it shouldn't be but i can't figure out why. i've gone over the tutorial again and read loads of documentation but i can't seem to get anywhere :/ I'll keep at it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your constructor in GameLoop.java. The line `this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;`
should be  `this.surfaceHolder = surfaceholder;` Note the capital 'H' in your original code.

If you're using an IDE, you would've seen a warning such as "The assignment to variable surfaceHolder has no effect" on that line.

Comment: oh flippin'eck you're completely right! i looked over and over for a typo round that line but i just didn't see it! Thanks so much for taking the time to find it, really! what a silly sausage..